# button clicked in one fragment action in anther fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Actually in my project when I click one `button1` in one fragment then it performs some operation in `onclick()`.  The problem is when I click another `button2` in another
fragment then also perform above operations (button1 operations)
What do I do to solve this?

```
 example
  class barfragment extends Fragment{

 button1.setonclicklistener(this);
  onclick(){
  FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmenetManager().beginTansction();


 }
  }
  class inframoation extends Fragment
     {
     BarFragment br=new BarFrgment();
      button2.setonclicklistner(br);
     }
```

is it work?
we get null pointer exception at  **ft**  when i click **button2**
but when iclick **button** then we dont get error
what is reson

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button click on a Fragment has issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573123/button-click-on-a-fragment-has-issue)

Comment: @ajay: you've already asked this question. Even on a forum, such multiposting is discouraged. SO, however, uses a Q&A format. Any duplicate questions, even ones that duplicate someone else's, will get closed. Read the FAQs for more on how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: The Fragment `br=new BarFrgment();` is null. Communication between the fragments isn't done like this. Involve the activity they are present on or use `static` key work with br.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  Fragment newFragment;
  if(v == btnFragment1)
  {
   newFragment = new MyFragment();
  }else{
   newFragment = new MyFragment2();
  }
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);
  transaction.addToBackStack(null);
  transaction.commit();
 }};
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're binding your button in BarFragment's onCreateView declare it like this ;
btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
And check your ids. probably they have the same id. Try giving different ids